# Should I Save My Mortar Bed?

Tags: bathroom, tile, mortar

I am in the process of ripping up my tile floor for a guest bathroom remodel. I discovered that my floor tile was installed on top of an old school mortar bed. Huge chunks of mortar have pulled away from the wall and there are also small divots. Should I attempt to patch the mortar bed or should I remove the entire bed and install something like Wedi backer board? My concern with tearing out the mortar bed is that my subfloor may not be level and I may need to use a floor leveler (which would add a lot more work).

If I were to patch the mortar board any suggestions on what type of patch compound I should use? Or it I tear out the mortar bed would type of backer board I should use? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Mortar Bed]

Comment: Are you wanting to keep the current height, or remove the thickness of the mortar bed?

Comment: Mortar will not help but be in the way There is also no humidity barrier under it as showing in the floor condition.

Comment: To Ruskes' point, are you able to get underneath that floor to see what condition the subfloor material is in?

Comment: Spuck. keeping the current hight is fine by me. A little lower would be okay as well. Brhans, the subfloor although discolored is dry. I don't use this guest bathroom for showers so I think the old water damage is old.

Comment: I'd remove it.  No way to tell what the subfloor looks like without removal—the exposed part looks a bit rotten to me.  Do you want to risk your new floor on a questionable subfloor?  Worst case you need to get some plywood to make up the thickness after removing the mortar bed.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove it. The effort to remove just the tile only and the thinset, to try to leave the mud bed, will take a lot of time. Not only that, but the mud bed will most likely crack all the way through in places, if it hasn't already.

To set tile on any floor, at least with this type of base, it must be monolithic, no cracks that make each section between the cracks "little islands". Not something to start building on and not expect to crack on through to the new tile. You could introduce an anti-fracture membrane, but with all the extra effort, I wouldn't chance it.

Comment: Thanks, @jack. I think I knew the answer already but needed confirmation from someone else. I'll take up the mortar bed and probably install new plywood or cement board.